# Semi-transparent background for image

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, transparency

I would like to add a semi-transparent background to an eps figure in `beamer`. The picture itself has transparent background. I want to add the semi-transparant background as I use the `tikz` package to overlap it with a first figure whose overlaped parts should still be visible. Here is the code I have so far:

```
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (img1) {\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{figure1}};
            \visible<2>{\node (img2) at (img1.south east){\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{figure2}};}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure of having understood your question correctly. Hence this is shooting blindfolded. Do you mean some thing like this?

You can use `opacity=<value>`. The MWE is :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (img1) {\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
            \visible<2>{\node[opacity=0.7] (img2) at (img1.south east){\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}};}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For me both the images A and B do not have transparent background. Since your image is already having a transparent backgound, I have no idea of how it will be. Please feed back.

**Edit:**

Following the comments, this is the next *guess* in trying to accomplish the goal.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (img1) {\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
            \visible<2>{\node[opacity=0.9,fill=red!90] (img2) at (img1.south east) {\phantom{\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{tansparent}}};
            \node (img2) at (img1.south east) {\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{tansparent}};}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here an articial bounding box is used with the help of `\phantom`.

[image]

Comment: No, thats not what I want. I want that figure2 is completely visible (opacity 1). But figure2 has now a completely transparent background. Hence figure1 is visible too. But I want to cover figure1 partly so there is no confusion between the two. In other words: your guess is good except: the letter B should be visible with opacity 1. And my figure 2 does not have a background now so I want to add a transparent one.

Comment: Thats the good direction. figure2 gets a white background now which hides (as it should) the overlap of figure1. However for me the background appears completely opaque so that the overlap of figure1 is completely invisible...

Comment: @highsciguy: I don't have a transparent picture. Hence I am not able to test anything. What I can do is only guessing. Posting your second image will make my life easier.

Comment: I cannot post it as an image. Format not supported. Can I upload a file somehow?

Comment: Not necessary. Your last edit works, except for the color:)

Comment: @highsciguy: Glad it worked. With all details provided, the chances of you getting better answers, fast, will improve. Color  can easily be changed according to your needs. BTW, If the answer solved your problem, you may also consider upvoting it besides accepting.